# Am I being scammed?

Tags: debit-card, fraud, scams

A friend of mine who recently got involved with some money hooked me up with a person and they asked for my debit card and account information. If you’re getting money transferred to you does that person need your card?

Comment: If you need to ask, the answer is probably "yes".

Comment: you are absolutely being scammed.

Comment: You may want to terminate this friendship ASAP.

Answer (score 11):

> a friend of mine got involved with some money recently

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what it means to "(get) involved with some money".

What does that mean?

> she hooked me up with the person and **they asked for my debit card and account information**. If you’re getting money transferred to you does that person need your card?

Yes, they're trying to scam you.

http://blog.nasafcu.com/2015/09/instagram-money-scam-involves-your-debit-card-and-pin/

> It’s a variation of the money flipping scam. The nice person holding a wad of 20 dollar bills in a photo claims it and more can be all yours if you just send her your debit card and PIN so she can deposit money directly into your account. And if it is that easy to get rich, why wouldn’t you do it?
>
> The scammers actually may deposit money in to your account with a check. Then, shortly after, you will see a withdrawal of a much larger amount. The check was fake, of course, and not only does your new Instagram contact disappear with your money, but you may also owe the bank some fees as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Close that account now!

By account information, what do you mean?  If they asked for the stuff the bank would ask you to prove that you are the owner of the account, congratulations you just gave them your identity.  Not only close that account but switch banks and start a identity theft protection service. You might not see a hit on the account right away.  Most identity thieves put together a portfolio (bundle) of bank accounts before selling them off.

Before I thought about the above, I was thinking money laundering.  They would run illegal money through several accounts to hide the source of that money.  The bad thing here is that if someone starts following that trail, you are on the hook for a major crime or, if you lucky and cooperate, a minor crime but you are still on the hook.  They will usually still charge you with something as the "cost of being stupid" (deterrent for everyone you might tell).

*Note: that quote above is from an actual LEO who was describing an incident.*

Note that if all they are doing is depositing checks or auto payments in you account and taking the cash out, they may just be hiding their income (divorce, welfare, court judgement, etc.).  They are still committing fraud and you are still helping them commit fraud.  See above for the reaction of law enforcement.  This seems less likely to me since they are recruiting multiple people but still possible.

They will probably launder money until they sell your identity.